# Download a .txt file with CakePHP 2.X

Tags: php, file, cakephp, download

I'm trying to download a .txt file using CakePHP.
The .txt file contains

```
0 6652,20
0003,24
```

In my controller I use this :

```
$this->response->file($myFile->path, array('download' => true));
return $this->response;
```

But when I check the file downloaded, I just have this :

```
0 6652,
```

When I check the file directly by FTP I can see the file is complete, but when I download it with CakePHP it's not complete ... where's my mistake ?

Thanks

Comment: It should work. Try some debugging. E.g. `pr($this->response);` before `return`, to make sure it's the right file, folder, size, etc.

Comment: @InigoFlores I tried debug($this->response);
it's the right file and size but still incomplete after the download ... I tried an other file, like a php script and it works but not for this file .. I really don't understand

Comment: It may be a cache issue. Try disabling it with `$this->response->disableCache();`

Comment: I put the disableCache(); before, still incomplete.
Are there any other way to simply download a file ?